# SQL Inner Join Help Needed

Tags: sql, integer, inner-join, varchar

I have the following query below:

```
SELECT 
[dbo].[history].histtable,
[dbo].[history].code,
[dbo].[history].Date,
dbo.Activities.Number,
dbo.table1.Itemnumber

FROM [dbo].[History]
INNER JOIN 
[dbo].[Activities]
ON
[dbo].[History].Flags=[dbo].[Activities].Objects

INNER JOIN dbo.table1 
On
CONVERT (Int, dbo.table1.Itemnumber) = CONVERT (INT, dbo.history.Date)
OR CONVERT (Int, dbo.tablenumber.Itemnumber) = dbo.Activities.Alltransactions

ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

and I keep getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value Itemnumber to data type int.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I would look for a value in the column ItemNumber which in fact can't be converted to int. And if you expect values to be an int, save them as int!

Comment: so hope my answer helped you out. if so please mark as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a separate select for each table that you are joining and use [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) to pull out only the rows that are not numeric so you can better identify your problem and see what values are not numeric

something like

```
select Itemnumber
from dbo.table1 
where IsNumeric(Itemnumber) = 0
```

or in you join, something like

```
INNER JOIN dbo.table1 
On IsNumeric(dbo.table1.Itemnumber) = 1 
and 
(
    CONVERT (Int, dbo.table1.Itemnumber) = CONVERT (INT, dbo.history.Date)
OR
    CONVERT (Int, dbo.tablenumber.Itemnumber) = dbo.Activities.Alltransactions
)
```